# given a system of N linear equations, Is there an algorithm that can find a solution that solves the most number of equations in this system

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, algorithms, linear-transformations, systems-of-equations

My apologies if this question makes no sense; I am trying to find an algorithm that can solve a linear system of equations. Unlike most problems like this- for this particular case, this algorithm does not need to find a solution set that solves the entire set of equations. It only needs to solve the MOST number of these equations. For example, if a given linear system has n equations, then the solution set returned by the algorithm should 'fit' the most possible number of equations in the system.

example: if there are N linear equations in a system S of linear equations, then the algorithm should return a solution set that solves m linear equations in S, where m<=N.

Based on what I have researched, none of the algorithms I know of will do this. (All of the ones such as Gauss elimination, least squares, etc.tries to solve the entire system). Hopefully I am just missing something and I can get pointed into the right direction. Thanks.

Comment: just pick any $m$ equations and solve the system. As you will have extra variables, the solution will be expressed in terms of these extra variables. Please note that in general there will be infinite number of solutions if $m<N$

Comment: Sounds similar to compressed sensing, you want $\min_{x,y} \{||y||_0 \mid Ax+y=b\}$.